# Testing a python script which use a subprocess to spawn a bash subshell .. is it possible?

Tags: python, unit-testing, bash

I have a quite complex project which I'd like to test .. but I can't find how to test it entirely.

The project itself is a development environment for django. It consist of a Python script which can be used to create a new project or activate a development environment.

To activate a development environment, I use a technique similar Virtualenv. My python script invoke a shell script which itself source a rcfile.

It sounds more complicated than it really is. The work flow looks like this:

```
$ cd my-project/
$ duke dev
(my-project)$
```

duke is my Python script which call a bash script named dev. The dev script contains only a  line like this:

#!/bin/bash
   . /path/to/bin/env

So it basically just starts a subshell in which I source a rcfile named env.

The env itself take care to create all the necessary commands and environment variables needed while developing.

My problem is that I cannot test anything that is specific to this env because my script spawns a subprocess which then activate the env in a subshell. The subprocess closes and the subshell is left open until I exit it.

While it works, I can't find a way to reliably test it.

Is it even possible to test this ?

Here's the code:

- **Invocation of the dev script:**
  https://github.com/h3/django-duke-client/blob/master/dukeclient/commands/dev.py#L22
- **The dev script template:**
  https://github.com/h3/django-duke-client/blob/master/dukeclient/templates/dev
- **The env rcfile template:**
  https://github.com/h3/django-duke-client/blob/master/dukeclient/templates/env

Answer (score 1):

Any script you run will always spawn a subshell.

You should call `. %(base_path)s/.duke/bin/env` before you start your python code, either on the command-line or as part of the same script which spawns the python.

Don't forget to export variables and functions which you may use in sub-processes.

Comment: This is pretty much the conclusion I've come to so far.. Now the question I ask myself is if it's possible for a subshell to exit itself. If it can, I might be able to call my script with a test flag to make the env run a test suite on activation and then exit. If it works it would probably fix my problem.